# Ordering Array - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, sorting

I am loading a listBox full of strings from a string array with a foreach statement. The strings say "Level 1" through "Level 20" and eventually further. It orders them as Level 1, Level 11, Level 12, Level 13, etc, skipping level 2, 3, 4 etc.

How can I order this correctly?

I am about to remove "Level " so it is just the numbers in the array then add them to the listBox with "Level " added. But performance is an issue with this WPF page and this may not be the best performance way.

Thanks.

Comment: See: [Natural Sort Order in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/248603)/412770

Comment: You should have some object with `Level` property, use some `SortDescription` based on that `Level` instead. That way we can order easily than based on the string presentation of the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the strings really do comprise a number prefixed with "Level " and that you already have an array of the strings then you could use this:

```
    var orderedEntries = from entry in entries orderby entry.Length, entry select entry;
    foreach (var entry in orderedEntries)
    {
        // TODO - add to WPF control
    }
```

However, from a performance perspective you'd be better off sorting an array of the numbers first and then prefixing each entry with "Level ".

Comment: Thanks. That way seems like it will work well but if my original idea is not any worse for performance, I will go with that as I've already done it. Good to know.